# How to expose read-only collection another type of private collection?

Tags: c#, .net

Here is my problem: there is a class that contains a inner collection (or list, or array, or something like this) of some some class and It must expose a public read-only collection of items, which are properties (or fields) of relative items in inner collection. For example:

```
//Inner collection consists of items of this class
class SomeClass
{
  public int _age;

  //This property is needed for exposing
  public string Age { get { return this._age.ToString(); } }
}

//Keeps inner collection and expose outer read-only collection
class AnotherClass
{
  private List<SomeClass> _innerList = new List<SomeClass> ();

  public ReadOnlyCollection<string> Ages 
  {
     get 
     {
       //How to implement what i need?
     }
  }
}
```

I know a simple way to do this by the use of a pair of inner lists, where the second keeps values of needed properties of first. Something like this:

```
//Inner collection consists of items of this class
class SomeClass
{
  public int _age;

  //This property is needed for exposing
  public string Age { get { return this._age.ToString(); } }
}

//Keeps inner collection and expose outer read-only collection
class AnotherClass
{
  private List<SomeClass> _innerList = new List<SomeClass> ();
  private List<string> _innerAgesList = new List<string> ();

  public ReadOnlyCollection<string> Ages 
  {
     get 
     {
       return this._innerAgesList.AsreadOnly();
     }
  }
}
```

But I dislike this overhead. May be there is some way to do what I want with exposing interfaces. Help me, please!

Hurra!
It seems that the best solution has been found. Due to the post of [Groo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/69809/groo)

this problem found its almost universal answer. Here is It (we need to add two entity):

```
public interface IIndexable<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    T this[int index] { get; }
    int Count { get; }
}

class Indexer <Tsource, Ttarget> : IIndexable<Ttarget>
{
    private IList<Tsource> _source = null;
    private Func<Tsource, Ttarget> _func = null;

    public Indexer(IList<Tsource> list, Func<Tsource, Ttarget> projection)
    {
        this._source = list;
        this._func = projection;
    }

    public Ttarget this[int index] { get { return this._func(this._source[index]); } }

    public int Count { get { return _source.Count; } }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return GetEnumerator(); }

    public IEnumerator<Ttarget> GetEnumerator()
    { foreach (Tsource src in this._source) yield return this._func(src); }     
}
```

With them, our implementation looks like this:

```
//Inner collection consists of items of this class
class SomeClass
{
  public int _age;

  //This property is needed for exposing
  public string Age { get { return this._age.ToString(); } }
}

//Keeps inner collection and expose outer read-only collection
class AnotherClass
{
  private List<SomeClass> _innerList = new List<SomeClass> ();
  private Indexer<SomeClass, string> _indexer = null;

  public AnotherClass () 
  { this._indexer = new Indexer<SomeClass, string > (this._innerList, s => s.Age); }

  public IIndexable<string> Ages { get { return this._indexer; } }
}
```

Thank Groo and the rest who answered. Hope, this helps someone else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The overhead is not so significant if you consider that `ReadOnlyCollection` is a **wrapper** around the list (i.e. it doesn't create a copy of all the items).

In other words, if your class looked like this:

```
class AnotherClass
{
    private ReadOnlyCollection<string> _readonlyList;
    public ReadOnlyCollection<string> ReadonlyList
    {
        get { return _readonlyList; }
    }

    private List<string> _list;
    public List<string> List
    {
        get { return _list; }
    }

    public AnotherClass()
    {
        _list = new List<string>();
        _readonlyList = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(_list);
    }
}
```

Then any change to the `List` property is reflected in the `ReadOnlyList` property:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AnotherClass c = new AnotherClass();

        c.List.Add("aaa");
        Console.WriteLine(c.ReadonlyList[0]); // prints "aaa"

        c.List.Add("bbb");
        Console.WriteLine(c.ReadonlyList[1]); // prints "bbb"

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

You may have issues with thread safety, but exposing `IEnumerable` is even worse for that matter.

Personally, I use a custom `IIndexable<T>` interface with several handy wrapper classes and extension method that I use all over my code for immutable lists. It allows random access to list elements, and does not expose any methods for modification:

```
public interface IIndexable<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    T this[int index] { get; }
    int Length { get; }
}
```

It also allows neat LINQ-like extension methods like `Skip`, `Take` and similar, which have better performance compared to LINQ due to the indexing capability.

In that case, you can implement a projection like this:

```
public class ProjectionIndexable<Tsrc, Ttarget> : IIndexable<Ttarget>
{
    public ProjectionIndexable
         (IIndexable<Tsrc> src, Func<Tsrc, Ttarget> projection)
    {
        _src = src;
        _projection = projection;
    }

    #region IIndexable<Ttarget> Members

    public Ttarget this[int index]
    {
        get { return _projection(_src[index]); }
    }

    public int Length
    {
        get { return _src.Length; }
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable<Ttarget> Members

    // create your own enumerator here

    #endregion
}
```

And use it like this:

```
class AnotherClass
{
    private IIndexable<string> _readonlyList;
    public IIndexable<string> ReadonlyList
    {
        get { return _readonlyList; }
    }

    private List<SomeClass> _list;
    public List<SomeClass> List
    {
        get { return _list; }
    }

    public AnotherClass()
    {
        _list = new List<SomeClass>();
        _readonlyList = new ProjectionIndexable<SomeClass, string>
             (_list.AsIndexable(), c => c.Age);
    }
}
```

**[Edit]**

In the meantime, I [posted an article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/collections/iindexable-read-only-list.aspx) describing such a collection on CodeProject. I saw you've implemented it yourself already, but you can check it out nevertheless and reuse parts of the code where you see fit.

Comment: Thta is a great solution at first blush. I didn't even know that readonly collection can synchronize with List by such a easy way.

Comment: @Praetor12: its properties just call the parent list's properties, so you don't need to create a new instance on each access. But the latter solution (`IIndexable`) is the preferred one since you don't need to keep a projected copy (a list of strings) at all, but rather project each item as needed.

Comment: @Praetor12 it's not a synchronization it's the same thing. It's only a different way of accessing the same object

Comment: IIndexable is useful interface, and its absence in .net is strange. I can't use IEnumerable because I need indexer this[index] and Length for exposing collection. I suppose IIndexable may be used with foreach cycle and some LINQ expressions. Only need to implement IEnumerable(of T).

Comment: @Praetor12: There is now [an article on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/collections/iindexable-read-only-list.aspx) describing IIndexable. Although you have implemented it yourself already, you can check out some additional extension methods which make its usage a bit simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just return IEnumerable?

If you have access to LINQ (.NET 3.5) then just use a select()

```
public IEnumerable<string> Ages{
   get{
      return _innerList.Select(s => s.stringProperty);
   }
}
```

Comment: this might change every time you enumerate it ... and my answer got downvoted because it's not immutable .... ;)

Comment: Yeh well I guess I didn't really understand the requirement. :) Oh well

Comment: IEnumarable haven't indexer this[index] and property Length. And Select will be executed each time when Ages would be called. In found solution new list is not created by anyone, we simply replace Enumerator ^))

Answer (score 1):

in this case I normaly just use IEnumerable - if the collection is readonly and you don't need the Index-functionality you can just do somehting like this:

```
public IEnumerable<string> Ages
{
   get
   {
      return this._innerList.Select(someObj => someObj.Age).ToArray();
   }
}
```

Comment: That's not a read-only collection that's an array of strings (very writable) exposed as an IEnumerable<string>. It does not change the original sequence but to me that simply makes it worse. The write will assume the changes are actually made but instead they are disregarded. Kinda like the problems you get with mutable structs.  What would be the reason to call ToArray anyways?

Comment: it does not matter how it is exposed (in the end EVERYTHING is mutable inside the computer) - even if you cast it back to an array you cannot change the ages of the SomeObjects inside the object so this exposes them very immutable...

Comment: @RuneFS: calling ToArray is actually the safest thing to do. Not the best solution performance-wise, but much safer than exposing a mutable list through `IEnumerable` (like Daryl suggested). And it is immutable as it can get: caller cannot change the source list anyway, and if some really crazy part of code wants to mutate it, it won't affect any other caller (`ToArray()` ensures that). Also, if the source thread is modified on a separate thread, caller won't get an exception while iterating a copy. My greater concern is that OP actually wanted to expose a collection, not an enumerator.

Comment: @Carsten which is exactly my point. So one can go and write code like ((string[])Ages)[0] = "10";
and expect Ages.First() to be "10" this is conceptually close to loosing the change of a temp variable when having mutable structs. Not saying it would be wise to do so but dislike code that makes it possible none the less

Comment: @Groo Daryl is not exposing a mutable list, he's exposing a projection of a mutable list. The projection is immutable and thread safe as long as the original list is kept thread safe.

Comment: @Rune this is nonesense - first the caller would have to know this implementation detail and second he could always call ToArray himself with every collection and to the same - nice that you indeed discuss your downvote though - normaly you don't see this

Comment: @Carsten I guess we just have to agree on disagreeing :)

Comment: @RuneFS, What do you mean by "kept thread safe"? The only way to ensure thread safety for an `IEnumerable` would be to allow external code to lock on the same sync object as the internal "thread safe" list, and exposing this is a deadlock waiting to happen. Google it. Check [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/safe_enumerable.aspx), for example. And I have never yet seen a library which would expect that its callers **cast** an IEnumerable in order to modify the wrapped contents. I didn't understand what you were saying at first, but I agree with Carsten, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Groo at that case you didn't understand what I said. There's no reason to make even an unlikely but failing scenario possible. Thread safe IEnumerables are easy to make. I don't know why any one would think other wise: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/12/10/immutability-in-c-part-four-an-immutable-queue.aspx. And it's not a matter of what the library writers expect for the library to work correctly we're debating it's the reverse. You code a library so that people can't do what they shouldn't be able to and since there's no reason for the ToArray but could create issues->don't

Comment: there is a reason - the object you get back should stay the same no matter what happens - it will create a lot of nasty problems if you don't pay attention and do something like this. I've seen it all: problems with LINQ (connection got disposed), threading-issues, etc. - and as I said: if you go deep enough you can allways change the data (Reflection) - BTW if the array is bugging you that much just wrap it in yet another readonly-collection ... but wait you could allways get the array back ... so it seems there is no solution for YOUR problem at all...

Comment: @RuneFS: "Thread safe IEnumerables are easy to make"? Are you aware that Lippert's article creates **immutable** queues? And it copies the **entire** queue in each Queue method to ensure that each caller gets a **new** instance, completely **opposite** of what you are advocating? Immutability is the safest approach when designing a library, and an entire paradigm of functional programming depends on it, which is one of the best ways to tackle parallel programming.

Comment: So, I will quote you (partially): yes, there is no reason to make a failing scenario possible. And there is nothing "unlikely" about iterating a collection on a different thread, so this is the part where you should focus your guard. Try to run this code, which simply does that: http://pastebin.com/CC8BLhAk. Nothing nasty, nothing "unlikely", but it fails as soon as you start it. Only because someone thought it would be nice to allow the user to have direct access to a collection through IEnumerable.

Comment: @Groo yes it's immutable and no it doesn't copy on every operation and it definately does not go against anything I advocate on the contrary

Comment: @Carsten except of course that that's not the case with the BCL. Just hake EF if you wish to have that guarantee you have to call ToArray explicitly yourself

Comment: @RuneFS: Check all the lines containing "`return new Queue<T>(...)`" expression. You should be able to realize that `return new Queue<T>` is conceptually the same thing as `return something.ToArray()` - it creates a **new immutable instance** which cannot possibly affect the previous instance. That is a much better solution, compared to returning an instance to your private data, because you want to give users freedom to modify the data in some bizarre way. I would avoid comparing your "IEnumerable casting" inventions to Lippert's immutable queues.

Comment: @Groo I'm not advocating any casting. I'm advocating using types that can't be misused even by the foolish (those that might cast to a different type than the declared return type) the not much to compare between creating an entirely new array copying every reference to simply adding ONE new one, which is what the Queue I liked to does. On top of that there's absolutely nothing you can do to the queue that will change it (as long as you don't do "bit fiddling"/hack the access restrictions). Those are two important properties that distinguish it from .ToArray().

Comment: @Groo and of course there's the point that .ToArray does not fix the issue you and Carsten is saying it does. It's not thread safe at all
var a = Ages;
var b = a;
Send a to one thread and b to another and modify one or both

Comment: @RuneFS I guess you have a problem with the thread-safe thing. By thread safe *I* am not thinking of the result of `obj.Ages` - to be honest I don't care what the caller does with it. What I am thinking of is that once the got it, I cannot possible change it, no matter what **I** do to `obj`. The caller will get a fresh copy with the same strings thats true - but strings **ARE** immutable. As I allready asked you: what's the difference between your cast and just doing `obj.Ages.ToArray()` **for the caller**?

Comment: That the caller knows about the difference, has a choice to whether or not the overhead is needed or even makes sense. Not calling it will yield a new IEnumerable every time sure changes to the original will result in an error if you are in the middle of an enumeration but that's true for your code to. However you _force_ the enumeration on the caller. What if the enumerations isn't needed? Ages.Any() might break in your code simply because you call ToArray

Comment: as another example contrary to the usual recommendation calling Count() would actually be better tha Any() using your code. That goes against the rule of "least surprise" in this particular case there not much harm in it but I still think always coding for "least surprise" is valuable

Comment: Your first point is valid but easily handled by approbiate locking on the server side - your client on the other hand has no way to lock anything as long you don't expose some kind of very unstable locking (isn't that very suprising too)? If you want thread-safe lazy enumerations you HAVE to generate them in an immutable-FP like manner (no side-effects) - in this case this is not possible because the objects with Ages might change - so better force the enumeration than break the client code in an unpredictable manner.